# Bit array from string

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, byte, bit

I've got a string:

```
cipher = "0111101110010111001001010000000110101000001000111101110000110101100100001100101100000"
```

I want to slice it and store in array like this:
["01111011", "10010111" ... ]

I tried this code, but i've got an error:

> "cz.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method`push' for nil:NilClass
>   (NoMethodError)"

```
i,j = 0,0
cipher_byte = []
while i < cipher.length
  if i != 0 and i % 8 == 0
   j+=1
  end
  cipher_byte[j].push(cipher[i])
  p cipher_byte
  i+=1
end
```

What's wrong with this?
It's ruby.

Comment: Your `cipher` string contains 85 characters. How should the remaining 5 characters be handled?

Comment: @KarolMazurek : Check the value of `j`. I bet it is an index outside of the `cipher_byte` array by the time the error occurs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cipher.scan(/.{8}/)
  #=> ["01111011", "10010111", "00100101", "00000001", "10101000",
  #    "00100011", "11011100", "00110101", "10010000", "11001011"]
```

Comment: Note that this solution leaves out trailing characters if not dividable by eight.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest:

```
cipher.each_char.each_slice(8).map(&:join)
```

Faster:

```
(0...cipher.length).step(8).map { |i| cipher[i, 8] }
```

Less code means less places an error could hide (as long the code is still readable). Ruby provides many idioms and methods to make things very intuitive and easy on the programmer. A `while` loop with a counter is rarely Rubyish; a `while` loop with an unconditionally incrementing counter never is.

Answer (score 3):

You're indexing an empty array (cipher_byte) and getting nil. Then calling push on an instance of nil

You'll want to create a new array every etc iterations, then push that sub-array to the main array.

Comment: aka, put `cipher_byte[j] ||= []` before the line `cipher_byte[j].push(cipher[i])`. Which assigns the current `cipher_byte[j]` to an empty array if it's currently falsy.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push to `cipher_byte[j]`, which, as the error is telling you, isn't set to a value yet. (On the first iteration of the loop, you can imagine that `cipher_byte` is of length 0, since it's set to `[]`. Therefore, you cannot yet index into it using `[j]`.)

You may want `cipher_byte.push`, rather than trying to push to a specific position. In Ruby, `.push` on an array will add that value to the end of the array; you don't need to reference that position with `j`.

Comment: _"you cannot yet index into it using [j]"_ – you can. `Array#[]` returns `nil` if the index is out of range. That's why the OP is getting a `NoMethodError` for `nil` rather than an `IndexError`